# how often do I have to re-authenticate using oauth 2.0

Tags: authentication, oauth

I am following the instructions here:

http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication

To authenticate access to the pocket API.

My question is how much of this do I have to do the second time a user uses my app?

I presume that I retain one of the tokens or codes and use that the second time. I certainly don't see the authentication page every time I used Tweetdeck for example.

What best practice is there for giving a user an option to not automatically sign them in next time if its a public computer for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the access token that you get during the "first" process, meaning the first time the user authenticated. Then you can use it for the next times.